# JBoss 7.1 failing to deploy war

Tags: java, jboss

I thought I had everything I need, but I get this error:

```
0:44:36,127 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."myapp.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."myapp.war".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "myapp.war"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]

Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: Error loading jboss-structure.xml from C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments\myapp.war\WEB-INF\jboss-deployment-structure.xml
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:277) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:249) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.deploy(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:134) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
... 5 more

Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,1]

Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2}jboss-deployment-structure'
at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:108)
at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:271) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
... 8 more
```

This is what my xml file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
<deployment>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
        <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
        <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
        <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
        <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
        <module name="org.slf4j" />
        <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
    </exclusions>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Am I missing something here? I thought the namespace was required? Can anyone shed some light on why my application won't deploy?

Comment: Which exact version of JBoss 7.1 are you using? As I understand, some shipped with the 1.1 xsd for deployment-structure and some with 1.2 and it maybe that you're trying to use 1.2 with a version that does not include it.

Comment: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final AS Certified Java EE 6 Full Profile 2012-03-09 LGPL Community participation only ZIP (127MB)
Release Notes http://download.jboss.org/jbossas/7.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.zip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2"` part.

Comment: Maybe that is because the value is not an URI.

Comment: whats the URI? I see a URN in the namespace